# Eagle automatically making connections to layers of PCB?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, pcb-layers

I'm designing a 4 layer PCB, using positive and negative power planes along with a ground plane and a top signal layer. While making the schematic I've notice strange little Xs in some of the through holes of my through hole parts. Here is an example. [image]

I'm wondering if the little cross in the middle of the through hole means that a connection is being made from pin 4 of this chip to the VS- layer. In other words, is the via connecting the VS- layer (layer 15) to pin 4 unnecessary?

Also, I know that the via shows up as a design rule violation. I need to change the minimum blind via ration for this board, and I'm not looking for advice about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the via is unnecessary. Any through-hole connection can connect directly to any layer in the board.

Answer (score 0):

The cross indicates a "thermal relief" connection to the plane.  The horizontal and vertical tracks make the connection to the plane, and the darker non-copper areas around the pad provide a thermal break, so you can more easily solder the component lead to the hole.

Without the thermal relief, you would have to heat a large area of the plane to make a good solder joint.